# Send email via Qt

Tags: c++, qt, email, smtp

i'm trying to send an email via qt i'used this code but i recive this error "4----  "502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. q9sm1859778wjo.9 - gsmtp\n" and thanks for your help. 
smrp.h

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>

#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDate>
#include <QLocale>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>

/*
  USAGE!
  Smtp *newMail  = new Smtp("remoteserver","username","pass");
  newMail->Send("from@address.com","to@address.com"," Your Subject","My body text");
  class emit ErrorCloseAll() / SuccessQuit()   or get QStringList ErrorMSG; to read error and data....

*/
class Smtp : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
            Smtp(QString smtphost, QString smtpusername, QString smtppass);
            ~Smtp();
            void setConfig(QString smtphost, QString smtpusername, QString smtppass);
            void send( const QString &from, const QString &to,const QString &subject, const QString &body );
            int linesend;
            QStringList errorMSG;
            QStringList getErrorlist();
    signals:
            void status( const QString &);
            void connectorSuccess();
            void sendLine();
            void errorCloseAll();
            void successQuit();

    private slots:
            void disconnected();
            void connected();
            void readLiner();
            void putSendLine();
    private:
            bool isconnect;
            QString smtphost;
            QString smtpusername;
            QString smtppass;
            QString message;
            QString output;
            QString RemoteServerName;
            QString mailstatus;
            QTextStream *t;
            QTcpSocket *smtpsocket;
            QString from;
            QString rcpt;
            QString response;
            QString sendLineAndGrab(QString senddata);
            int Timeout;
            QString encodeBase64( QString xml );
            QString decodeBase64( QString xml );
            int dateswap(QString form, uint unixtime );
                QString TimeStampMail();


};
#endif
```

*smtp.cpp*

```
#include "smtp.h"

Smtp::Smtp(QString smtphost, QString smtpusername, QString smtppass)
{
        qDebug() << "### Class Smtp start";
        this->smtphost = smtphost;
        this->smtpusername = smtpusername;
        this->smtppass = smtppass;
}
void Smtp::setConfig(QString smtphost, QString smtpusername, QString smtppass)
{
        this->smtphost = smtphost;
        this->smtpusername = smtpusername;
        this->smtppass = smtppass;
}

void Smtp::send( const QString &from, const QString &to, const QString &subject, const QString &body )
{
        int waittime = 5 * 1000;
        this->from = from;
        rcpt = to;
        errorMSG.clear();
        Timeout = waittime;
        linesend = 0;
        isconnect = false;

        message = TimeStampMail()+"\n";
        message.append("User-Agent: Mozilla Thunderbird 1.0.6 (Macintosh/20050716)\n");
        message.append("X-Accept-Language: zh_CN, zh_CN\n");
        message.append("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
        message.append("To: " + to + "\n");
        message.append("From: "+from+" <" + from + ">\n");
        message.append("Subject: " + subject + "\n");
        message.append("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8;\n");   /* or txt */
        message.append("Content-transfer-encoding: 7BIT\n\n\n\n");
        message.append(body);
        message.replace( QString::fromLatin1( "\n" ), QString::fromLatin1( "\r\n" ) );
        message.replace( QString::fromLatin1( "\r\n.\r\n" ),QString::fromLatin1( "\r\n..\r\n" ) );

        smtpsocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
        connect( this, SIGNAL(connectorSuccess()), this ,SLOT(readLiner()));
        connect( this, SIGNAL(sendLine()), this ,SLOT(putSendLine()));
        if (smtphost.size() > 0)
        {
                smtpsocket->connectToHost("smtp.gmail.com",25);
                qDebug()<<"meh";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug()<<"mele7";
                smtpsocket->connectToHost("localhost",25);
        }
        if (smtpsocket->waitForConnected(Timeout))
        {
                if (smtpsocket->waitForReadyRead(Timeout))
                {
                        isconnect = true;
                        emit connectorSuccess();
                }
        }
        else
        {
                emit errorCloseAll();
            qDebug()<<"---close all ---";
        }

}

void Smtp::readLiner()
{
        if (isconnect)
        {
                QTextCodec *codecx;
                codecx = QTextCodec::codecForMib(106);
                t = new QTextStream( smtpsocket );
                t->setCodec(codecx);

                int loops = 0;
                while (!t->atEnd())
                {
                        loops++;
                        response = t->readLine();
                }
                if (response.size() > 0)
                {
                        RemoteServerName = response;
                        mailstatus = response.left(3);
                        if (mailstatus == "220")
                        {
                                response="";
                                linesend = 1;
                                emit sendLine();
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        emit errorCloseAll();
                    qDebug()<<"here";
                }
        }
}

Smtp::~Smtp()

{
}

/* LINE SENDER  */
void Smtp::putSendLine()
{
        int current = linesend;
        switch(current)
        {
                case 1:
                        response = sendLineAndGrab("ehlo " + smtphost);
                        if (response.size() > 0)
                        {
                                errorMSG.append(response);
                                linesend = 2;
                                emit sendLine();
                        }
                        response ="";
                        break;
                case 2:
                        response = sendLineAndGrab("AUTH LOGIN");
                        if (response.size() >=0)
                        {
                                errorMSG.append(response);
                                linesend = 3;
                                emit sendLine();
                        }

                        response ="";

                        break;
                case 3:
                        response = sendLineAndGrab(encodeBase64(smtpusername));   /* username send */
                        if (response.size() > 0)
                        {
                                errorMSG.append(response);
                                linesend = 4;
                                emit sendLine();
                        }

                        response ="";
                        break;
                case 4:
                        response = sendLineAndGrab(encodeBase64(smtppass));     /* pass send */
                       qDebug()<<smtppass;
                        qDebug() << "4---- " << response;
                        if (response.size() > 0)
                        {
                                errorMSG.append(response);
                                if (response.contains("235", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
                                {
                                        linesend = 5;
                                        emit sendLine();
                                }

                        }

                        response ="";
                        break;
                case 5:
                        response = sendLineAndGrab("MAIL FROM:<"+from+">");
                        if (response.size() > 0)
                        {
                                linesend = 6;
                                emit sendLine();
                        }

                        break;
                case 6:
                        response = sendLineAndGrab("RCPT TO: <"+rcpt+">");
                        if (response.size() > 0)
                        {
                                errorMSG.append(response);
                                response ="";
                                response = sendLineAndGrab("DATA");
                                if (!response.contains("not", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
                                {
                                        errorMSG.append(response);
                                        response ="";
                                        linesend = 7;
                                        emit sendLine();
                                }
                        }
                        response ="";
                        break;
                case 7:
                        response = sendLineAndGrab(message+"\r\n.");

                        if (response.size() && response.contains("ok", Qt::CaseInsensitive) )
                        {
                                errorMSG.append(response);
                                linesend = 8;
                                emit sendLine();
                        }
                        response ="";
                        break;
                case 8:
                        sendLineAndGrab("QUIT");
                        break;
                default:
                        /*emit ErrorCloseAll();*/
                        return;
                        break;
        }
}

/* SENDER AND RECIVER  */
QString Smtp::sendLineAndGrab(QString senddata)
{
        QString incommingData = "";
        if (isconnect)
        {
   /////////QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::WaitCursor));
                int current = linesend;
                int loops = 0;

                *t << senddata << "\r\n";
                t->flush();
                if (senddata != "QUIT") {
                        if (smtpsocket->waitForReadyRead(Timeout))
                        {
                                while (!t->atEnd())
                                {
                                        loops++;
                                        QString opera = t->readLine()+"\n";
                                        incommingData = opera + incommingData;
                                }
                        }
                } else
                {
          ////////QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
                        delete smtpsocket;
                        delete t;
                        isconnect = false;
                        emit successQuit();
                        return incommingData;
                }
    ///////QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
        }
        else
        {
                emit errorCloseAll();
        }
        return incommingData;
}

void Smtp::disconnected()
{
        qDebug() <<"disconneted";
        qDebug() << "error "  << smtpsocket->errorString();
}
void Smtp::connected()
{
        output.append("connected");
}

QString Smtp::encodeBase64( QString xml )
{
        QByteArray text;
        text.append(xml);
        return text.toBase64();
}

QString Smtp::decodeBase64( QString xml )
{
        QByteArray xcode("");;
        xcode.append(xml);
        QByteArray precode(QByteArray::fromBase64(xcode));
        QString notetxt = precode.data();
        return notetxt;
}


QStringList Smtp::getErrorlist()
{
        return errorMSG;
}

int Smtp::dateswap(QString form, uint unixtime )
{
        QDateTime fromunix;
        fromunix.setTime_t(unixtime);
        QString numeric = fromunix.toString((const QString)form);
        bool ok;
        return (int)numeric.toFloat(&ok);
}


QString Smtp::TimeStampMail()
{
        /* mail rtf Date format! http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc788.html */
        QDateTime timer1( QDateTime::currentDateTime() );


        uint unixtime = timer1.toTime_t();
        QDateTime fromunix;
        fromunix.setTime_t(unixtime);


        QStringList RTFdays = QStringList() << "giorno_NULL" << "Mon" << "Tue" << "Wed" << "Thu" << "Fri" << "Sat" << "Sun";
        QStringList RTFmonth = QStringList() << "mese_NULL" << "Jan" << "Feb" << "Mar" << "Apr" << "May" << "Jun" << "Jul" << "Aug" << "Sep" << "Oct" << "Nov" << "Dec";
        QDate timeroad(dateswap("yyyy",unixtime),dateswap("M",unixtime),dateswap("d",unixtime));

        QStringList rtfd_line;
        rtfd_line.clear();
        rtfd_line.append("Date: ");
        rtfd_line.append(RTFdays.at(timeroad.dayOfWeek()));
        rtfd_line.append(", ");
        rtfd_line.append(QString::number(dateswap("d",unixtime)));
        rtfd_line.append(" ");
        rtfd_line.append(RTFmonth.at(dateswap("M",unixtime)));
        rtfd_line.append(" ");
        rtfd_line.append(QString::number(dateswap("yyyy",unixtime)));
        rtfd_line.append(" ");
        rtfd_line.append(fromunix.toString("hh:mm:ss"));
        rtfd_line.append(" +0100");

        return QString(rtfd_line.join(""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really Qt related, just SMTP settings.

From your code I see you are using gmail and port 25. This is not correct, change your outgoing port to 465, see [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/gmail/computer-email-program-please-specify-apple-mail-outlook-thunderbird-etc/vgudVNFLH7s)